# "Fatal Python error: deallocating None" and urlgrabber

Tags: python

I'm trying to fetch 1m+ pages over HTTP from single site. urlgrabber seemed like fast solution using "keep alive" connections. However, after a while my script fails without any stack trace with: "Fatal Python error: deallocating None"

Here is isolated python code that fails (for simplification, file:// URL is used, gives same results):

```
import urlgrabber

url = "file:///some/existing/file.html"

for i in range(0, 15000):
    print i
    handle = urlgrabber.urlopen(url, timeout = 1)
    # do something useful
    handle.close()
```

It fails after ~3231 cycles.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What Python version are you using? Get the latest (2.7.1 in 2.x branch). Maybe the bug is fixed there.

Comment: This sounds like a bug related to the object reference counter, better check from the module developer.

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/yum-devel@linux.duke.edu/msg00000.html looks like urlgrabber is leaking fds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody else mentioned, urlgrabber's got issues when you run this many grabs. Also, this is going to be unhappily slow if you're really grabbing hundreds of thousands of URLs. As an alternative, consider either the trusty wget.

Of course, you're going to say that you want a Python solution, and for that, you should definitely check out Scrapy at http://scrapy.org/, which is generally agreed to be the best way to do this kind of massive scraping.